# (fractals) What is the link between my bifurcation diagram of a population and the mandelbrot set?

Tags: fractals

This is my first time here as I'm investigating fractals.

I started of by writing about the similarity between a bifrucation diagram of a population, using formula $z_{n}=a*z_{n-1}*(1-z_{n-1})$.

I ended up getting the following image:[bifurcation diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjXcS.png)

I compared this to the mendelbrot set, without seeing to much similarity at first, but in a youtube video, I saw that there 2 are very similar, when placed on top of eachother:[Mendelbrot set, placed on bifurcation diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSHv4.jpg)

What could be a way of explaining the way that the periodic behaviour of both graphs are similar if not identical?
By taking the fracture of the lengths I discovered the Feigenbaum constant, 4,669... (as expected), though I was curious if there is another explanation for this behaviour.

Thank you all in advance.

Greetings!
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple change of coordinates between $x \to r x (1 - x)$ (Logistic Map) and $y \to y^2 + c$ (Mandelbrot set): $$c=\frac{1-(1-r)^2}{4}$$ $$r = 1 + \sqrt{1 - 4 c}$$

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Logistic_map#Very_old_discussions